# Is there a way to redeclare the scopes of an existing function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, scope, closures

I've run into this problem I would like a function to be accessible externally but it also needs to inherit some scope based properties because it's used in `JSON.stringify()` as an optional stringifier and so can't have additional context passed to it.

So let's say I have this code

```js
let object = {
  function1(){ 
    let a = 1
    console.log(object.function2()) // a is not defined undefined
  },
  function2(){ return a }
}
```

So I'm wondering if there's a way to change the closure/scope status of function2, like binding a new this context but binding a whole scope.

The only way I've figure out is

```js
let object = {
  function1(){ 
    let a = 1
    let function2 = eval('(function '+object.function2.toString()+')')
    console.log(function2()) // 1
  },
  function2(){ return a }
}
```

The reason for this is memory management as I don't want to be creating a new function everytime another function is called.

Comment: Doing this also breaks debugging capabilities in VSCode due to it being an eval'd bit of code

Comment: Why not just make `a` a property of `object`? Then `function2` can return `this.a`?

Comment: Or read the "Emulating private members" section of this: [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Comment: Can you provided an example of how the function should be "accessible externally". Maybe a more concrete example with expected results? There's other ways to pass data around and bind functions but I'm not sure what the requirements are.

Comment: `this.a` and maybe [`.bind(object)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for the JSON.stringify replacer

Comment: Please provide an example of what your actual problem is, i.e. how you want to use that function in `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @Matt externally accessible means accessible as a variable like object.function2 instead of having function2 defined inside function1, making it unreachable. This means you can modify the behaviour of function1 without actually overriding function1, since it uses an externally accessible function2

Comment: @Matt, unfortunately, JSON.stringify does it's own binding on the replacer function given when it calls it so that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there's a way to change the closure/scope status of a function, like binding a new this context but binding a whole scope.

No, this is not possible. Scope is lexical, and the scope chain of a function is fixed when the function is created. It must be immutable to allow the engine to optimise identifier resolution.

Your best bet is probably to set the value of a variable that is already in scope of the function.